# How can I get total float values in Odoo 11?

Tags: python, odoo-11, odoo-12

I want to get the total balances of these two float field. Can you please help!

`start_blc = fields.Float("Starting Balance")`

`end_blc = fields.Float("Ending Balance")`

`total_blc = fields.Float("Total Balance")`

Comment: Its a bit unclear, could you please explain what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Hello @AbbasEbadian,
Thanks for your comment, I want get the total float value of these two float values but I'm stock. Can you please help me with the function to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your total_blc to compute field

```
total_blc = fields.Float("Total Balance", compute='_compute_total')

@api.depends('end_blc', 'start_blc')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        record.total_blc = record.end_blc + record.start_blc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate!!

Comment: No problem, happy to help, feel free to mark this as the right answer too ;)